# Merge Replication: Error "The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check constraint"

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2005, merge-replication

For one of our SQL server 2005 enterprise, configured with merge replication, we suddenly start seeing the below error message:

> The insert failed. It conflicted with an identity range check
>   constraint in database 'ABC', replicated table 'dbo.tblMtxyze', column
>   'csa'. If the identity column is automatically managed by replication,
>   update the range as follows: for the Publisher, execute
>   sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange; for the Subscriber, run the
>   Distribution Agent or the Merge Agent.

I went through the complete process of rectifying as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/953481), but no luck.

We have about 10 publication from this single database ABC containing the filtered tables, around 6 and all of them going through same error:

Any idea how can i proceed from here, apart from setting up merge replication from scratch?

**Edit:**

On exploring more we found that out of those 10 Publications, we have one Publication which act as master Publisher which needs to be working in order  for rest 9 to work.

However, when we right click and went to properties of that publication, the articles( 6 common tables among all 10 pubs) were not at all present out there on this master publisher.

So we went ahead and try adding those articles , but it threw us error saying

> An article with a different subscriber_upload_options value already
>   exists for object '[dbo].tbl1

In order to resolve, we though this being master, went ahead and removed one article at a time from other 9 publications, thus allowing that table1 to show in article on master publication.

But again, the same thing goes if i try to add removed articles back to other 9 publications with same error.

What can be done here? We are out of thoughts for now as this merge replication seems very complicated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share any more information on what you saw (or did not see) when going through the complete process?

Comment: As mentioned on doc i ran SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('<TableName>') and for all the 6 tables and as per script for result where op was 0 aded+1 for min value found and where o/p greater than 0, added+1 for high ident value found.

Comment: Although it may not be ideal, did you try `sp_changemergepublication '<PublicationName>', 'max_concurrent_merge', 1` to see if merging one subscription at a time does resolve the error?  And are you running at least SQL Server 2005 SP2 Cumulative Update 8?

Comment: Yes i tried, and its SP4, but no luck

Comment: Ok, i just found something. Here is this one master Publisher which manages other publishers. Now when i see its articles, there are none of those 6 tables which other publisher have. I tried adding those 6 tables in articles but get the error message "An article with a different subscriber_upload_options value already exists for object '[dbo].[Material]'."

Comment: In 2011 Hilary Cotter, a replication expert, gave an answer referring to sp_addmergearticle to your "different subscriber" message at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ef4b73e0-1c61-4907-867d-e785cc5f2b88/rmo-an-article-with-a-different-subscriberuploadoptions-value-already-exists-for-object?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: @RLF, i created a sql login and gave access to the database as datareader and then created this master publisher with "@check_permissions = 1" as mentioned , login to the instance with this newly created login, but  but got the error saying "Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed database role can perform this operation. Contact an administrator with sufficient permissions to perform this operation".